# files path in different folders in html

Tags: php, html

I have the following folder structure with files:

```
index.php
includes/header.php
includes/conn.php
contents/ad_list.php
contents/ad_posting.php
```

in my `index.php` I have the following include

`include("includes/header.php");` its ok

but in `contents/ad_list.php` the above include give the following error:

```
Warning: include(includes/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\NAYAAD\contents\ad_list.php on line 4
```

I couldn't solve this problem.

Regards:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to go up one level:

```
include("../includes/header.php");
```

Comment: thanks dear Mike GB, my includes/header.php has link to includes/conn.php and on every page I include includes/header.php so it displays my header and includes/conn.php connect to database. now on 1st include("../includes/header.php"); in my index.php solve the problem but from index.php when I click on link to contents/ad_list.php it don't find the includes/header.php and also includes/conn.php.

Comment: Have you tried including it as the file only (since both files are in the same directory)?

include('conn.php'); inside header.php

Comment: good. its okey. but the others files and different folders have problems.

Comment: Now I am unable to link my css style,  '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" />' the includes/header.php is link to this file and both are in the same folder.

Comment: Does '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />' work?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `include("../includes/header.php");` solve the problem, but, the best way is known root of your application and use it for base for includes.

You need to set `include_path` in your `php.ini` relative to your application root folder, or, try with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: by using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; its now ok, but I have to specify full path for files.

Answer (score 0):

Try including dirname on your inclusion.

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__)."/../contents/ad_list.php";
?>
```

the dirname(_FILE) can make it more portable and depending on where its running, you could just copy it up and add dots as needed.

Comment: If you need to use your php via cronjob or via commandline, the dirname() is sometimes needed.

Answer (score 0):

try put a "." infrontof the address

```
include("./contents/ad_list.php");
```

Comment: Firstly you're trying to include the wrong file, and second of all the "." means "from the same directory". You need ".." to go up one level.

Comment: this soloved my problem: ' include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/conn.php");'